# Gmail - forward all emails received except from one email address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I just set up an email account for my daughter and as part of the deal for her getting an account is that I get copied on all email for the next year. I've easily set up the account to forward to me all email received.

What I would like to add to the filter is to not forward emails that come from my own address as I will obviously know what's in them.

Ideally I would also like to not forward emails where I'm cc'd (from my wife and grandparents or other family members).

Is this possible?

Comment: Gmail will forward every single email but you may setup a filter at your end to automatically trash such email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In her account you may turn off forwarding then create a filter `from:-dad@gmail.com` and check forward to `dad@gmail.com`

Comment: bizarrely this solution https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73962/how-to-get-gmail-to-forward-all-mail-except-from-a-certain-address  seems to mention  turning on forwarding and then doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't provide such an option, but Microsoft Outlook does have option as per your need and many more filtering options.

So, if it is really important to you then you can use Microsoft Outlook in place of Gmail. Please note that it can also be used in a browser like Gmail.