# How to get Gmail to forward all mail except from a certain address?

Tags: gmail

How can I get Gmail to automatically forward all mail *except* from a certain address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the Gmail Settings by clicking on the gear in the upper right corner:

[image]

2. Go to "Forwarding and POP/IMAP".
3. Click on "Add a forwarding address" and enter the email address to which you want to forward emails.
4. In the email account to which you are forwarding, you will receive an email with a verification link.  Click on that link.
5. Back in your Gmail account, go to "Filters".
6. Click on "Create a new filter" and enter `-name@domain.com` in the From field.  Make sure to put a minus sign in front of the email address - that will make it forward all emails except ones from that address.
7. Click on "Create filter with this search".
8. Check the "Forward it to" box and select the email address to which you want to forward those emails.  The email address that you validated should be in the dropdown box.
9. Click on "Create filter".

Comment: "-name@domain.com" Great! Trying now. Thanks. What's the official source for this info?

Comment: @ChrisJJ On this [Google support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), you can see that it says: "The 'or' function in Gmail is represented by 'OR,' and the 'not' function is represented by a minus (-)."  That's why putting the minus sign in front of the email address will have it forward those emails that do NOT match that address.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Also, Gmail has help pages describing how to [automatically forward emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en#10957) and how to [use filters](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).

Comment: "On this Google support page," Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how to get to "Gmail Settings"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Done.

Comment: @Peter "a minus sign in front of the email address - that will make it forward all emails except ones from that address" Is this actually documented/defined behaviour?