# How do I disable Gmail forwarding for just a single sender

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

Until now I have forwarded all incoming Gmail to a daytime address. I would say about 50 people regularly correspond using this Gmail address.

Now I want to use it for a new private correspondence, and for that single sending address, do not want these emails forwarded. I don't want to have to setup 50 forwarding rules just to exclude one.

Is there a way to setup an exclusion rule to forwarding?

For example, if there is a filtering rule on the new address just to label those mail messages, will this *de facto* avoid them being processed by the blanket forwarding rule?

Answer (score 1):

In the forwarding filter, you should put a `-` (minus sign) in front of the email address to be excluded. See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73983) helpful Q&A and Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en#10957):

> If you only want to forward certain kinds of messages to another
>   account, create a filter for these messages.

Comment: Spot on, thanks SImlev.

So the answer was to disable blanket forwarding and setup a single filter with -<email address to exclude>  and the filter rule is to forward as before.